# Auto stats update ruining background?

Tags: postgresql

I tried to understand the Auto stats update process, as of now I see auto Vacuum and stats settings both are independent. But I always see only auto vacuum is running background not auto Analyze.

Do I missing anything as I never see auto analyze running through Pg_stat_activity.

where to see live analyze running status(Auto only, Manually I can see verbose/Pg_stat_activity)?

I tried by same vacuum settings and both different settings, I always see only auto vacuum triggered not analyze.

Answer (score 1):

`ANALYZE` is usually much faster than `VACUUM`, so I am not surprised if you never catch one running. Look at `pg_stat_user_tables` to see when last and how often autoanalyze did run on your tables.